# Python test - Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

Tags: python, function, class, testing, assert

I created the following test function for a python script.

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
     def test_log_model(self):
        response = requests.post(
            url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/log_model',
            json={
                "data_dir": os.path.join(base_dir, 'dataset', 'diabetes_dataset.csv'),
                "scaled_data_dir": os.path.join(base_dir, 'output', 'scaled_dataset.csv'),
                "label": column_label,
                "new_variable_name": new_variable_name,
                "output_dir": output_dir
            }
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.text, {'C': 0.0001, 'penalty': 'none', 'solver': 'lbfgs'})

if __name__ == "__main__":
     unittest.main()
```

When I run the testfile, I get:

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

I would like something like this:

```
Ran 1 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

How can I solve?

Comment: The code you have posted does not reproduce the problem you are describing.

Comment: It depends how you launch the script. If you launch it on the command line like `python -m unittest mytest.py` it will work. If you launch it from a IDE such as PyCharm you need to configure the run configuration to be a unittest (not just ordinary `run`, which only executes the code above the line `if __name__ == "__main__":`